# Weird Rounding Occurs in C++ Function

Tags: c++, floating-point

I am writing a function in c++ that is supposed to find the largest single digit in the number passed (inputValue). For example, the answer for .345 is 5. However, after a while, the program is changing the inputValue to something along the lines of .3449 (and the largest digit is then set to 9). I have no idea why this is happening. Any help to resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

This is the function in my .hpp file

```
void LargeInput(const double inputValue)
//Function to find the largest value of the input
{
  int tempMax = 0,//Value that the temporary max number is in loop
  digit = 0,//Value of numbers after the decimal place
  test = 0,
  powerOten = 10;//Number multiplied by so that the next digit can be checked
  double number = inputValue;//A variable that can be changed in the function
  cout << "The number is still " << number << endl;
  for (int k = 1; k <= 6; k++)
  {
    test = (number*powerOten);
    cout << "test: " << test << endl;
    digit = test % 10;
    cout << (static_cast<int>(number*powerOten)) << endl;
    if (tempMax < digit)
      tempMax = digit;
    powerOten *= 10;
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: Mandatory reading: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Why do maths? Just format the number with `snprintf()` or `asprintf()`, iterate over the result, and look at the digits individually.

Comment: @millimoose: Formatting with `asprintf` or `snprintf` is problematic because the number is already represented in binary floating-point when it is passed to this function. Therefore, either the number to be examined is exactly the double that is passed (and its decimal representation in the example does contain “9”) or some error has already been introduced. If some additional information were added, such as that the number is actually intended to be the six-digit decimal numeral closest to the double that is passed, then using a function from the printf family would be a feasible approach.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot represent real numbers (doubles) precisely in a computer - they need to be approximated. If you change your function to work on longs or ints there won't be any inaccuracies. That seems natural enough for the context of your question, you're just looking at the digits and not the number, so .345 can be 345 and get the same result.

Try this:

```
int get_largest_digit(int n) {
  int largest = 0;

  while (n > 0) {
    int x = n % 10;
    if (x > largest) largest = x;
     n /= 10;
  }
  return largest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the fractional component of real numbers is in the form of 1/2^n. As a result you can get values very close to what you want but you can never achieve exact values like 1/3.

It's common to instead use integers and have a conversion (like 1000 = 1) so if you had the number 1333 you would do `printf("%d.%d", 1333/1000, 1333 % 1000)` to print out 1.333.

By the way the first sentence is a simplification of how floating point numbers are actually represented. For more information check out; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Representable_numbers.2C_conversion_and_rounding

Answer (score 0):

This is how floating point number work, unfortunately.  The core of the problem is that there are an infinite number of floating point numbers.  More specifically, there are an infinite number of values between 0.1 and 0.2 and there are an infinite number of values between 0.01 and 0.02.  Computers, however, have a finite number of bits to represent a floating point number (64 bits for a double precision number).  Therefore, most floating point numbers have to be approximated.  After any floating point operation, the processor has to round the result to a value it can represent in 64 bits.

Another property of floating point numbers is that as number get bigger they get less and less precise.  This is because the same 64 bits have to be able to represent very big numbers (1,000,000,000) and very small numbers (0.000,000,000,001).  Therefore, the rounding error gets larger when working with bigger numbers.

The other issue here is that you are converting from floating point to integer. This introduces even more rounding error.  It appears that when (0.345 * 10000) is converted to an integer, the result is closer to 3449 than 3450.

I suggest you don't convert your numbers to integers.  Write your program in terms of floating point numbers.  You can't use the modulus (%) operator on floating point numbers to get a value for digit.  Instead use the fmod function in the C math library (cmath.h).

Comment: When `.345*10000` is converted to an integer, the result is of course closer to 3449 than it is to 3450, because the result is exactly 3449. You may have intended to say that the result is 3449 because `.345*10000` is closer to 3449 than it is to 3450, but that would be false. When “.345” in the program source text is converted to an IEEE-754 double and multiplied by 10000, the result is 3449.999…, which is obviously closer to 3450 than to 3449. The reason the result of converting this to integer is 3449 is because conversion to integer is specified to truncate, not to round to nearest.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have indicated, binary floating-point is incapable of representing most decimal numbers exactly. Therefore, you must reconsider your problem statement. Some alternatives are:

- The number is passed as a double (specifically, a 64-bit IEEE-754 binary floating-point value), and you wish to find the largest digit in the decimal representation of the exact value passed. In this case, the solution suggested by user millimoose will work (provided the `asprintf` or `snprintf` function used is of good quality, so that it does not incur rounding errors that prevent it from producing correctly rounded output).
- The number is passed as a double but is intended to represent a number that is exactly representable as a decimal numeral with a known number of digits. In this case, the solution suggested by user millimoose again works, with the format specification altered to convert the double to decimal with the desired number of digits (e.g., instead of “%.64f”, you could use “%.6f”).
- The function is changed to pass the number in another way, such as with decimal floating-point, as a scaled integer, or as a string containing a decimal numeral.

Once you have clarified the problem statement, it may be interesting to consider how to solve it with floating-point arithmetic, rather than calling library functions for formatted output. This is likely to have pedagogical value (and incidentally might produce a solution that is computationally more efficient than calling a library function).